# Plotear con diferentes colores centroides

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Buen día, estoy intentando mostrar centroides en un conjunto de datos previamente cargado a un plot, los centroides deberian de colocarse de distintos colores, si intento usar el parámetro c con un arreglo de colores me marca error y sin eso funciona y usa colores aleatorios, pero por alguna razón se repiten, es decir, si tengo 20 centroides (valor de K), solo se pintan usando 10 colores distintos, siendo así debería mostrar 20 colores distintos uno para cada centroide, pero no funciona.

**Python 3.7**

```
mapa_colores = cm.jet
plt.title('Centroides en el conjunto')
plt.xlabel('Atributos 1')
plt.ylabel('Atributos 2')
plt.scatter(conjunto_t[0, :], conjunto_t[1, :], 10)

for i in range(0, K):
   plt.scatter(centroides[0, i], centroides[1, i], 70, marker='o', 
   cmap=cm.viridis)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los puntos encerrados en el circulo, repiten los colores, existe alguna forma para que sean diferentes, de antemano gracias.

---

*No estoy usando keras, ni seaborn, estoy haciendo todo el algoritmo de kmeans a mano con puro numpy, lo menciono por que con keras es muy facil, pero aqui no puedo.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tener 20 colores diferentes, habría que eligir un colormap con 20 colores diferentes. En la documentación hay una [lista de las posibilidades](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). El cmap 'tab20' parece lo más adecuado. Aún asi hay un par de colores que se parecen bastante.

Los colores de Viridis no tiene suficientes diferencias en los colores para distinguir 20.

```py
for i in range(K):
    plt.scatter(centroides[0, i], centroides[1, i], 70, marker='o',
        color=plt.cm.tab20.colors[i%20])
```

Otra posibilidad seria emplear 'gist_rainbow'. Tiene como conveniente que no hay la limitación de 20 colores, pero no son *tan* diferentes que 'tab20'.

En código:

```py
for i in range(K):
    plt.scatter(centroides[0, i], centroides[1, i], 70, marker='o',
        color=plt.cm.gist_rainbow(i / (K - 1)))
```

El siguiente imagen muestra la diferencia entre los colormaps:
[image: diferencia entre colormaps]

Comment: No amigo, por alguna razón, los colores no varean, disminuya o aumente K, los colores se repiten cada 10, probablemente el problema no sea el color, sea otra cosa pero no se que pueda ser.

Comment: ¿Sigues llamandolo como `scatter(..., cmap=...)`? Eso no tiene efecto en el bucle. Con `scatter(..., color=...)` tendrás control sobre los colores.

Comment: Ya lo resolví amigo, usando la propiedad color que me enseñaste, genere un arreglo con flotantes al azar para después convertirlo en una tupla que simulara los canales rgb y de este modo en el bucle recorrerlos.
<br>
# Colores
colores = np.random.random_sample((K,3))
colores_t = tuple(map(tuple,colores))
print(colores_t)
<br>
Dejándolo de este modo:
for i in range(K):
    plt.scatter(centroides[0, i], centroides[1, i], 70, marker='o', color=colores_t[i])
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

La solución efectiva fue, generar un arreglo de flotantes al azar y convertirlos a tupla.
Debido a que los colores que generaban los mapas de colores eran muy similares.

## Colores

```
colores = np.random.random_sample((K,3))
colores_t = tuple(map(tuple,colores))
print(colores_t)
```

[image: Salida print(colores_t)]

## Cargando los colores de la tupla

```
for i in range(K):
   plt.scatter(centroides[0, i], centroides[1, i], 70, marker='o', color=colores_t[i])
plt.show()
```

[image: Colores mas aleatorios]

En donde se nota mas el cambio es al momento de clusterizar los atributos.

[image: Atributos clusterizados por centroide]

De antemano gracias a ***JohanC***, que acerco mas a la solución.